# В чем отличие методов get() и valueAt() класса SparseIntArray?

Tags: android

В чем отличие методов get() и valueAt() класса SparseIntArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SparseArray:**

`get()` получает объект сопоставленный с указанным ключом. или null, если такого сопоставления нет.

`valueAt()` возвращает значение из сопоставления значений ключа index, которое хранится в этом SparseArray. Диапозон  *0 ... size()-1*